# Polygon class using the STD Vector class

Tags: c++

The code below represents a polygon. I want to be able to push a point (a gvector3 object for x,y,z) onto the vector "vertices." I know that vector has a push_back method, but since I've declared vertices as private, I don't think I can call vertices.push_back(gvector3 xyz). Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could implement this?

```
#ifndef POLYGON_H
#define POLYGON_H

#include <iostream>
#include <gvector3.h>
#include <vector>

class Polygon {

private:

   std::vector <gVector3> vertices;
   std::vector <gVector3> color;

public:

///----------------------------------------------------------------
/// Constructors
///----------------------------------------------------------------
/// Default constructor
Polygon();


///----------------------------------------------------------------
/// Getters and Setters
///----------------------------------------------------------------
/// Return vertex / reference to vertex at index
gVector3 operator[](unsigned int index) const;
gVector3 &operator[](unsigned int index);

///----------------------------------------------------------------
/// Draw Polygon
///----------------------------------------------------------------
void drawPolygon(const Polygon &p);

};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Polygon p);

#endif // POLYGON_H
```

Comment: Implement a [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) (or some other more appropriately named) member function for your class that then calls `vertices.push_back()`

Answer (score 1):

Give your polygon a method to add vertices?

```
void Polygon::addVertex(const gVector3 &vec) {
    vertices.push_back(vec);
}
```

Comment: oh right, I forgot that I can acess private fields through functions!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1. Add a public method that will push the `gVector3` for you as [in Mark H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21666074/1097451)

   or
2. Change the design. Make the Polygon a `struct` instead of a `class` and provide the drawing functionality in the form of **freestanding functions**.

   ```
    struct Polygon
    {
       std::vector <gVector3> vertices;
       std::vector <gVector3> color;
    };

    void drawPolygon(const Polygon &p);
   ```

I see that you already provide direct access to the data with your **getters and setters** so you might as well make the data public. C++ has support for object objected programming, but you should use objects only when you have some functionality to **encapsulate**.